# How can I snap the customize image cursor with a vertical line using JS?

Tags: javascript, css, image, cursor, timeline

The effect is similar to the Facebook timeline, and you move your mouse near the the blue vertical line, it will turn to a blue cross, and you can add post on click.

I know I can customize  cursor using css like: cursor:url('cross.png'), auto; but is there a method I can control the cursor on the web page, and make it move only vertically? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change the cursor position using JS and using png as a cursor is not browser friendly at my knowledge.

So the best solution is using cursor:none; in your css to hide the cursor. So you can show the image at the required position, and change it's y position using the mousemove event.

e.g.
in css

```
.line{position:relative;cursor:none;}
.btn-plus{background:url('cursor.png') no-repeat;position:absolute;}
```

in js

```
$('.line').mousemove(function(e){
    var btn_cross = $(this).find('.btn-plus');

    if (btn_cross.length == 0)
    {

        btn_cross = $('<div class="btn-plus"></div>');

        $(this).append(btn);

        btn_cross.mouseenter(function(){

            e.stopPropagation();

        });

    }

    btn_cross.css('top', e.pageY-$(this).offset().top+'px');

});
```